# "No module named _struct" after manually building and installing python 2.6

Tags: dpkg

running Ubuntu 12.04, I had the usual python 2.7 in place .

I needed python 2.6 , so I downloaded the source and did

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

A mistake, as I did not want to replace my system-wide python . 
Now some programs stopped working , e.g. update-manager with

```
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

I used update-alternatives to make python 2.7 default again, but many python applications still won't start up because of some missing modules .

Can someone give a hint what happened and what the best way to fix it would be?

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

I could get some functionality of apt-get to work by setting my own hard link from /etc/python to /etc/python2.7 .
( So I guess using update-alternatives really did not do much good eithe. )
I did a dist-upgrade , which basically worked, but a lot of the package managing via apt-get is still broken.
In particular, a **problem with python-minimal** prevents many other installations of packages I wanted to do .

```
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
```

PS:
**Building 2.7 from source** always did exit (also before dist-ugprade or update-alternatives) with

```
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Currently, on make , there are more issues (" Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             bsddb185           bz2
dl                 imageop            sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
")

As this is a little over my head , I guess I am just better off with a fresh install from scratch .

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when I downgraded from debian/Testing to debian/Stable recently. I guess somewhere in the process, python modules got corrupted. Purging and reinstalling python was, as it was pointed out, a bit draconian. Thankfully, I came across the following
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693

Following this suggestion, I tried the command

```
for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | egrep -v 'deinstall' | egrep python | awk '{print $1}'`; do  apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

to reinstall anything that has python in its name, and that solved the problem.

Comment: This saved me... had to run it a couple of times until all package errors were resolved.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I get an infinite loop with unmet dependencies errors when executing the code provided. Can I force it do execute anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Your python 2.6 install has probably changed lots of settings and paths.

Your best bet is to reinstall the default python interpreter

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python python-support
```

I can't test it, but I hope that it works. Good luck.

If it doesn't work the only other idea that I have is to install python 2.7 from source, and afterwards trying to reinstall the default one again.

Comment: --reinstall sounded good but did not work , in fact due to a python error that came up in the process of running apt-get . Thanks anyways , though

Comment: Edited the answer, try to complie 2.7 from source and re-do the reinstall vodoo.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into essentially the same issue, but for python-minimal 2.7.11-1.

`cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst`

You should get something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

python2.7 -m compileall /usr/share/python/ >/dev/null
```

Run the command without redirect to >/dev/null (edit the file, or: `sudo python2.7 -m compileall /usr/share/python/`). This will show you where post installation configuration is failing.

Ex:

```
Listing /usr/share/python/penemue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent 
Compiling /usr/share/python/penemue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py ...
  File "/usr/share/python/penemue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 183
    def makefile(self, mode="r", buffering=None, *,
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In my case, it was a custom python package (built using dh-virtualenv) that lived under /usr/share/python. I had to run `dpkg -P penemue` and ultimately remove the `/usr/share/python/penemue` directory. I might have been able to just move the `/usr/share/python/penemue` directory out of the way.

Once I got rid of the bad code, running `sudo apt-get install -f` resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you accidentally got overwrote the default python directory (somehow) and 2.6 is incompatible with what update manager/apps need.

Try `sudo apt-get purge python2` then `sudo apt-get install python2`. This should purge python from your system and reinstall it, making it the default Python again.

Only other idea is that you got a bad source for 2.6 and it as such made a bad install that wasn't bad *enough* to be detected by make???

Comment: Doing apt-get purge python will remove a LOT of packages and components which I would have to re-install manually after re-installing python (?) . Would like to keep that as a last resort only ..

Comment: true. Though, if just reinstalling 2.7 via `apt-get --reinstall install python2 python2-support` doesn't work, it will be the best bet to go with.

Comment: Yes, --reinstall does not work . When purgeing, something went wrong, too . At the moment, I cannot use apt-get, because of (python) errors e.g. installing gtk components like checkbox , etc. I will now try to reset python - as this still seems to be the core of the problem - somehow manually.