# "ImportError: No module named _struct" configuring python-minimal

Tags: dpkg

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, the dpkg error appears and interupts the process.

Error details:

```
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python:
 python depends on python-minimal (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1); however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.
```

And this problem leads to a series of dependency problems when processing the following packages:

```
 python
 gwibber-service
 libgwibber3
 libgwibber-gtk3
 gwibber
 gwibber-service-facebook
 gwibber-service-identica
 gwibber-service-twitter
 python-all
 python-dev
 python-all-dev
 python-apt
 python-problem-report
 python-apport
 python-libxml2
 unity-lens-gwibber
 unity-scope-video-remote
```

Finally, nothing I can do for this problem. And several days later, the root directory is full and I even could not uninstall any software because of this problem.

Comment: possible duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/q/270011/169736

Comment: @Braiam, I've found this question before. The answers are suggested to reinstall python. I've tried, and failed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I changed my `/usr/bin/python` symlink to point to `python3.5` and it caused a very similar error to this. Not sure why, probably to do with already having `python2.7` deps that got broken when I changed the symlink without warning. IDK, leaving this here for future travelers

Answer (score 8):

Follow the solution by Soroosh. [Broken python (2.7) after manually building and installing python 2.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270011/broken-python-2-7-after-manually-building-and-installing-python-2-6/560317#560317)

Enter `sudo -i` for root access.

Paste the command and wait about 20 minutes.  Runs perfectly.

```
for pkg in $(dpkg --get-selections | egrep -v 'deinstall' | egrep python | awk '{print $1}'); do  apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, going through the packages, I found that python-minimal does not have struct.py, but python-minimal2.7 does.

So, try this and see if it helps you out:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7-minimal
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If even that does't work, perhaps your $PYTHONPATH is messed up somehow.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the line `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python2.7"` then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And try your update yet again.

Comment: edited to add "export", it's kind of necessary ;)

Comment: It says "Unable to locate package python-minimal2.7". Do you mean python2.7-minimal? When I try to reinstall python2.7-minimal, the same dependency problem occurs.

Comment: Hmm, sorry it took so long for me to get back to you. Try `sudo apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't work. After `clean`, `update` and `upgrade`, then I try to reinstall `python2.7-minimal`, but the same dependency problem appears and the `reinstall` fails again.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about which package. it's actually libpython2.7-minimal that contains struct.py. Make sure that's installed. What is the current version of python2.7-minimal that you have installed? Hint: `dpkg -l | grep python2.7-minimal`

Comment: (1) I search `libpython2.7-minimal` in synaptic, and there's no results.  (2) The version of my `python2.7-minimal` is `2.7.3-5ubuntu4.1`.  (3) My ubuntu is 12.10. Can I just download a `libpython2.7-minimal(Raring version)` and install it?

Comment: Possibly. It depends on the dependant package. Sometimes they depend on a specific version, but with something as widely used as python, I don't image that there would be any packages that have a python2.7-minimal = 2.7.3-Subuntu4.1 dependancy.

Comment: Try installing this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/python2.7-minimal/download. It's the same version as you have installed, but struct is clearly in there. Don't think you can do a --reinstall with the same version since it's updated now. But, once you install that, try to do your upgrade once more.

Comment: It's indeed that I can't install this one:python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-5ubuntu4_amd64.deb. It said that `A later version has been installed`.

Comment: Great! I've done sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.6-minimal and that's save my life!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt purge libpython*
```

I removed python2.7 and 3.7, then deleted related files from the system.
After that I found I can't reinstall python2.7
Tried many methods still not working, including :

> remove soft links
>
> del virtual env dirs
>
> autoremove
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1`
> ```

Then I found some libpython files by searching python whole system.(Do not rm files from dir if you are not sure.)
After removed `libpython*` packages(I removed them one by one.),  python installed successfully.

Hope this can help some people have same problems

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is going to help you out at all, it's a bit of a stab in the dark, but make sure your default Python version is set to 2.7.

There are three files of concern in /usr/bin:

```
python (symlink)
python2.7
python3 (symlink)
```

If you do `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python` you will see what each symlink points to.

If it shows you `python -> python3` or `python -> python3.3` there's something wrong. At this point you will want to:

```
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my `/usr/bin`, `python` is soft-linked to `python2.7`.

Comment: Why is this? I had changed my symlink to point to `python3.5`, and it borked a huge amount of python packages and `apt` as well. Why can't I default to Python3? What is the correct way?