# Error from install file: "No module named: _struct"

Tags: drivers, python

OK, so this all started trying to install OpenBazaar, but I've talked to their devs and it's my python that seems messed up somehow.  I think I may have created/deleted a symbolic link somewhere like a year or so ago, and have NO memory of what/where it was/is.

So I run their install and it stops at this error:

```
ImportError: No module named _struct
```

So naturally I start looking around for solutions to this.  I've seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150106/importerror-no-module-named-struct-error-when-managing-packages) one:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python python-support
```

But that doesn't fix it.  So I tried the one lower down in that same thread:

```
sudo apt-get remove idle-python2.7
```

But IDLE is not on my machine.  So my next guess is this one response to the same issue at http://bugs.python.org/issue15066, where the guy says he *reversed* the patch for the bug.  And I guess that's where my skills fall madly short, because I can't even figure out what that patch even means, let alone how to reverse it:

```
Index: Lib/site.py
===================================================================
--- Lib/site.py (revision 79298)
+++ Lib/site.py (working copy)
@@ -118,7 +118,7 @@
     s = "build/lib.%s-%.3s" % (get_platform(), sys.version)
     if hasattr(sys, 'gettotalrefcount'):
         s += '-pydebug'
-    s = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[-1]), s)
+    s = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path.pop()), s)
     sys.path.append(s)
```

Any guesses?  Any off-the-top-of-my-head s?
As I said, I'm pretty sure this is my own clumsiness at work, but I just want to see if anybody can tell me where to start looking for the shattered glass.

In my usr/lib folder, I have python2.7, python3, and python3.4, but I have no idea why I have three versions.  When I do `python -V` it comes up with:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

I'm really at a loss as to where to even begin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken python (2.7) after manually building and installing python 2.6](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270011/broken-python-2-7-after-manually-building-and-installing-python-2-6)